# Xubuntu half screen is distorted upon regular boot

Tags: xubuntu

When I do a regular boot up I get this half distorted screen but the other half is working fine.
I can access the whole screen only when I go to recovery mode and resume from there.
One post suggested to do `sudo service lightdm restart`, this didn't change anything.
I also cleaned and repaired any broken packages or whatnat.
Im on a samsung nc10 mini laptop

Pc specs:
Cpu: intel(r) atom(tm) cpu n270 1.60gh
Gpu?: 945gse express

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with netbook GPUs. To solve it, follow these steps:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. Change `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` (remove the `#`)
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot