# Editing xubuntus grub without gksu or gedit

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I come from here: [Xubuntu half screen is distorted upon regular boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043823/xubuntu-half-screen-is-distorted-upon-regular-boot)

The problem is that the grub file is read-only and has no write permission, this : [How to edit GRUB file at /etc/default/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294069/how-to-edit-grub-file-at-etc-default)

Suggests using gksu, but i dont have internet to install gksu, what can i do? 
Ps: i am in root and used nano and vi

Comment: What of `nano`, `vi`? `Nano` is way easier to use!

Comment: It doesn seem to matter, i guess my problem exactly is "how to get write permissions for /etc/default/grub"

Comment: ok, run `ls -l /etc/default/grub` and lets see the write permission status

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1237 <-- is the response

Comment: Now how did you get to know grub was read-only, as the permission on grub looks ok?

Comment: Did you try the solution offered you in your original issue

Comment: Well if i do (in root)-> nano /etc/default/grub -> already its saying : " no write permission" and if i still were to edit i get this : " modifying a file which is not locked, check directory permissions?"

Comment: Well to even solve my original issue i have to edit grub but as u can see i cant

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files

Comment: Use `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. It is not read only.

Comment: @mikewhatever wierd, its saying its readonly and no write perms, i am editing through recovery mode maintenence root , maybe thats the problen

Comment: Yup that it was

Comment: If you're editing through recovery mode the drive is probably in read only mode.  You will need to remount the drive as read write before you edit the file.  `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: @Terrance If your comment was written up as an answer I believe it would be useful to future users with the same issue..